# sending email with image using sendgrid

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, sendgrid

I am trying to send a mail with the image using sendgrid, but when I am attaching the file address as below:

> message.AddAttachment(Server.MapPath(@"~\C:\work\project\iv-ace\ace\images\Campaign-images\Diwali2.png"));"

I am getting an error:

> "[js] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning."

If I am removing "@" then I am getting error:

> "Server is not defined" and if I am removing "server.MapPath" then i am getting "message.AddAttachment is not a function"

What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in javascript? This looks like C# code to me...

Comment: yes its javascript

Comment: As far as I know SendGrid has an API based intergration. You can use javascript to send messages with that, but you will need to make some POST calls to send the message. What you have above is a C# (server-side) code. I think you are confusing them...

Comment: thanks for the response i am pretty new to these so may be i got confused can you give some examples regarging post calls

Comment: oh i fixed it you were correct it was c# thanks !